# Using a params condition to display a link_to when a user visits the show action on a specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How does one setup a condition if 'post_controller/show' is viewed.

I would like an 'Edit' button to display on the header navigation if the user is viewing the post, without setting up a different layout and have it just rely on the existing `_header.html.erb` for navigation.

```
# Header navigation partial _header.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Edit post', edit_post_path(@post) %>
```

I know I can take a param and set clause something like:

```
<% if params[:id] %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit post', edit_post_path(@post) %>
<% end %>
```

The problem with the above is it will cause an exception `undefined method 'edit_post'` if you visit a different route that doesn't relate to the Post model.

If I can get away from many layouts and partials that would great but if the suggestion is that I should be using layouts and partials in this scenario then I will.

Many thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Header navigation partial _header.html.erb
<%= yield(:edit_link) %>

#In your post_controller/show view :
<% content_for :edit_link, link_to('Edit post', edit_post_path(@post)) %>
```

And that's about it. You can change the content of `:edit_link` wherever you want, for different models etc ...

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for your wonderful response. I've added yield(:edit_link) to my header.html.erb partial and the content_for to my Post's show.html on the first line. Is it me, but is this weird I'm adding it in the show view.. it seems messy that it's in there and it's not actually displayed on that template.

Comment: Take a look at examples here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for . `content_for` is used when you want to change elements in your layout on a per-action basis, so I'm putting it at the very top of action specific view files ... same thing if you want to set specific meta title, description etc ... You can delegate this to a helper but that won't make a huge difference

Comment: Anthony, I appreciate you taking the time and your response has been insightful. Thanks for explaining the reasons behind the code, it's a great help! You're a gem.